# Create Search Form to Filter Through Terms

Tags: filters, search, terms

I have pages that displays a list / grid view of all my taxonomy terms. Over 200 terms. The page is paginated since there are so many terms, however, I would also like to include a "search" box at the top of the page that will allow a user to enter a term name and the list / grid below will auto update to show the search term(s) for the user to click. I will repeat this list displays TERMS, not the posts within.

I would also like the search box to be "live" so to speak and update the search results below actively depending on what the user is typing.

[This example on bootsnip](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/jquery-searchable-plugin) provides a sample of what I was trying to accomplish, however in testing, simply inserting the script links, the input string and `id="searchable-container"` did not work. The search box emptied my page as if it wasn't able to read through my terms.

If anyone has any solutions or alternative please let me know.

Comment: You could build something with a jQuery DataTable using server-side script to return tag links. http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html OR even just echo all the tags into a table and use `jQuery('#your-table-id').dataTable();` . It will create a great search feature for you.  Just make sure to include all needed scripts/css from DataTables.net

Comment: Thanks @Douglas.Sesar. I'm going to look at that! Hopefully it's not over my head :)

Comment: Just include the datatable javascript and css files correctly and the plugin should do all the hard work.